# ASP.NET MVC error cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.2

View - `MovieForm.cshtml`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Movie.GenreId)
    @Html.DropDownList(m => m.Movie.GenreId, new SelectList(Model.Genres, "Id", "Name"), "Select a Genre", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

View model - `MovieFormViewModel`:

```
public class MovieFormViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public Movies Movie { get; set; }  
}
```

Model classes:

```
public class Movies
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public int NumberInStock { get; set; }
}

public class Genre
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller - `MoviesController`:

```
public ActionResult NewMovie(int id)
{
    var movie = _context.Movies.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
        
    var viewModel = new MovieFormViewModel
        {
            Movie = movie,
            Genres = _context.Genres.ToList()
    };

    return View("MovieForm", viewModel);
}
```

My DbSet is:

```
public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
```

The only problem I have is in my view (`MovieForm.cshtml`).

This line of markup

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Movie.GenreId)
```

doesn't cause any errors, however this

```
@Html.DropDownList(m => m.Movie.GenreId, new SelectList(Model.Genres, "Id", "Name"), "Select a Genre", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

throws an error

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type.

This error is in `m.Movie.GenreId` which was was working fine in the previous line.

Comment: Change `DropDownList` to `DropDownListFor`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `DropDownList` to `DropDownListFor`.